# Frame per second in apportable's version of GLKit does not changes.

Tags: apportable

How I can change frame rate for GLKViewController in apportable framework?

I've tried just setup  `[self setPreferredFramesPerSecond:30];` , but not helped. Always 60.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setPreferredFramesPerSecond was not yet implemented.

We added the implementation today and it will be available in one of the next two SDK updates.

If you post a sample that demonstrates the issue, we'll test it out.

Comment: I logged this issue this morning: https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=660&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20BlockedOn%20Component%20FoundIn%20FixedIn ... could it be related?